# Use substring in Excel VBA with (xml)data

Tags: xml, excel, substring, vba

I'd like to do some simple substringing in Excel VBA, alas `string.substring(a,b)` does not seem to work.

I have before me a very simple xml format such as this one:

```
<result>
<rowset name="typeids" key="typeID" columns="typeName,TypeID">
<row typeName="Tritanium" typeID="34" />
<row typeName="Scordite" typeID="1228" />
```

more rows

```
</rowset>
</result>
</eveapi>
```

I'd ideally like to get an array or concatenated string with all typeIDs in the order  they appear here.

Now, I could of course just `InStr` myself to death, but I'd like to know whether one of you can come up with a more elegant solution since my VBA knowledge is quite limited.

I'd also be grateful for answers that just parse the xml instead of viewing it as a simple string - I'd generally just like to keep it on the simple side since this is my first contact with VBA ever.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Give us an example of the desired output.

Comment: I'm not picky in that regard, it could either be a string such as "34,1228,(etc)" or an array of integers of the typeIDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that the data occupies column **A**:

```
Sub FindTypeID()
    Dim sOut As String, st As String, N As Long, NN As Long
    Dim DQ As String
    DQ = Chr(34)
    s1 = "typeID=" & DQ
    s2 = DQ & " />"
    NN = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For N = 1 To NN
        st = Replace(Cells(N, 1).Text, s2, "")
        ary = Split(st, s1)
        If UBound(ary) = 1 Then
            sOut = sOut & "," & ary(1)
        End If
    Next N
    MsgBox sOut
End Sub
```

Comment: The Data exists as a String as a result of a webservice I've called - should've added that to the question.

How would I populate a Column with this data before calling your function (this is my very first contact with Excel VBA altogether)?

Comment: I am not sure..........can you get the webservice to store the data as a text file on your computer??................If yes, then we can import the file into a worksheet.

Comment: I just solved the problem myself without writing the data into a sheet first - I'll make sure to use a solution similar to yours in the future though, seems a little more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the most direct approach to solve this problem now.

In case anyone might be having the same problem in the future, here's the code I used -

```
If Len(xmlData) > 0 Then
      k = xmlData

    Do While InStr(k, "typeID=") <> 0
        j = InStr(k, "typeID=")
        k = Right(k, Len(k) - j)
        numberStart = InStr(k, """")
        numberEnd = InStr(numberStart + 1, k, """")
        numbers = numbers & Mid(k, numberStart + 1, numberEnd - numberStart - 1) & ","
    Loop
    numbers = Left(numbers, Len(numbers) - 1)
End If
```

The result is a String containing all the TypeIDs in a comma-separated fashion.